# How to deploy an MVC 3 app that needs a DB and some SSRS reports

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I just developed an MVC 3 app that uses some SSRS reports and has connects to a SQL server DB. I'm now in the time to move to production. I have to deliver a package with documentation to the prod team so they can deploy it as seamlessly as possible. It doesn't have to be a one click installer. It just have to be easy to delpoy.

How have you guys been deploying this kind of applications? I'm looking from the best cost effective way for my point of view.

Comment: did you find a solution? I find the approach changes depending on how you made the ssrs reports (eg will they render as local or server reports)